# Terse umbrella concept for data validation and standardization?

Tags: architecture, language-agnostic, terminology, conceptual

I want to write some code that handles both data *validation* (for example, "field X must be alphanumeric") and data *standardization* (for example, "coerce field X into upper case").  I'd like a rubric for this code that encompasses these two functions without being significantly less terse than either of them (as, for example, using `ValidationAndStandardization` would be).  An established term would be preferred, but inventions are better than nothing.

Comment: How about *qualification*?

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it is not about a practical programming problem as outlined in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 5):

I would use `parse`<sup>1</sup>.

Technically, parsing only requires recognizing that an input matches some particular grammar--that is, the qualification part you've mentioned.

That's almost always accompanied by transforming input that allows an (often large) number of variations, and transforming it into some format that's standardized and relatively easy for other code to deal with. In fact, the transformation step is so common that I'm pretty sure most programmers would *reject* the idea of code really being a parser if it *only* verified conformance with a grammar.

The canonical example would be a compiler's parser, which verifies that the input (your program) is syntactically correct, and typically also produces something like an abstract syntax tree--the input code transformed into a format that's easier to work with, recognize patterns, further transform, etc.

---

1. Paraphrasing parsimonious partners: parsing is paradise!